# n-ary connectives can be simulated with (n-1)-ary connectives

Tags: logic

The statement in the title is the short version. This is the complete theorem in my lecture:

> Every n-ary connective (n > 2) can be simulated with two (n − 1)-ary
>   connectives, binary connectives and negations.

And there's this statement to show this can be proved inductively

$M(p_1 ,...,p_{n−1} ,p_n ) ←→
[(p_n ⇒ M(p_1,..., p_{n−1}, true)) ∧ (¬p_n ⇒ M(p_1 ,...,p_{n−1} , false ))]$

But I can't find the (n-1)-ary connective in this example. $M$ is still n-ary even if one of its operands is $true$ or $false$.

Can anyone explain this to me? Or does anyone have any link to a page that proves this theorem step by step?

Comment: The $n-1$-ary connective is the connective $N$ defined by the equality $$N(p_1, \ldots, p_{n-1})=M(p_1, \ldots, p_{n-1},T).$$